# RMagick: get glyph metrics

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick, glyph

I can't find out how to get all metrics of a given glyph with RMagick.

I know there is a get_type_metrics method which gives the baseline, height, ascent, descent, etc, but I would also like to get the x-height, cap-height, bounding rectangle for a given glyph, etc. Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, this is not possible. RMagick is a (nice) binding to the [ImageMagick library](http://www.imagemagick.org/), and ImageMagick does not provide the information you are requesting.

The only [font metrics information available from ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#font_info) is shown in this example:

> Metrics: text: Test; **width:** 49.5; **height:** 29; **ascent:** 20; **descent:** -7;  **max advance:** 30;
>   **bounds:** 0.5,-3  25,16; **origin:** 49,0; **pixels per em:** 24,24;
>    **underline position:** -1.64062;
>   **underline thickness:** 0.78125

This is why [`get_type_metrics`](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/draw.html#get_multiline_type_metrics) only returns the information that it does.